Docker bind mount
I am a beginner in Docker.
I have a basic node app project "node-bind-mount-demo" on the below path on my local machine.

C:/Acer/Desktop/Docker_Demo/node-bind-mount-demo

This project contains index.js file which looks like below:


const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    return res.json({
        message: 'Welcome to home !'
    });
});

app.get('/info', (req, res) => {
    return res.json({
        message: 'Welcome to info !'
    });
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`Server up and listening at PORT ${process.env.PORT}`);
});



The package.json file inside the folder looks like below:


{
  "name": "bind-mount-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npx nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7"
  }
}



The Dockerfile inside the 'node-bind-mount-demo' folder looks like below:


FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm ci

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]



I am using docker build -t app-bind-mount-node . command to build the image
I did bind mount and ran the image using winpty docker run -it --init -p 3002:3000 -v "$(pwd)":/app app-bind-mount-node:latest command
The issue is that when I make changes to my

index.js

file inside the local node project those changes are not reflected inside the container and despite using nodemon my server does not restart inside the container.
I have done mount bind and checked the WORKDIR path and local directory path still I can't see any progress.
I am using GitBash and using Docker on Windows (WSL).

One of Docker's core features is that the container filesystem is isolated from the host's: the container can't normally see changes in your local environment, and your host system can't see core tools like npm or node inside the container.  For a development setup, I'd recommend just installing Node; there's no reason to bring Docker into it.

Do you run docker run ... in Windows or WSL ?

Are you not using a volume rather than a bind mount here?

inotify events are not sent from Windows to Linux under WSL2 as per this issue. So the container isn't told that a file has changed.
When you can't rely on inotify events, you have to use polling or as it's known in nodemon, legacy watch.
You enable legacy watch by adding the -L option to your nodemon command in your package.json file like this
"start": "npx nodemon -L index.js"


...is this a duplicate of Nodemon Doesn't Restart in Windows Docker Environment?

Don't know. I'm just here to help people.
